# fast scrambler for 1Gbit Ethernet

Tags: c++, c, driver, ethernet

I have to add scrambler for skb->data(socket buffer). When I try to scramble each byte in skb->data, the speed decreases 10 times.

```
for (i = 0; i < skb->len; i++){
    skb->data[i] = skb->data[i]^lfsr[i];                   
}
```

How can I scramble skb->data faster?
Update:
How can i scramble more than one byte in one iteration?

Comment: Scramble 4 or 8 bytes in one iteration, for instance.

Comment: also use in-place: `skb->data[i] ^= lfsr[i]; ` and compile with `-O2` to unroll loop / optimize. Please provide [mcve] so the code can be compiled/tested

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the pointer dereferencing, use in-place memory manipulation, and use OpenMP to parallelize the loop, like so:

```cpp
//Compile with -fopenmp flag
const int len  = skb->len;
auto &data = skb->data;
#pragma omp parallel for simd
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    data[i] ^= lfsr[i];
```